# Laravel 7 guard doesn't log in

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a question regarding to laravel 7 custom guard auth.

```
    $this->guard()->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
```

This line of code use the default guard 'web', which works just fine.

```
    $this->guard('agent')->attempt(
        $this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')
    );
```

This line of code use the custom guard 'agent', is has been configured correctly, as it does return '1' as true, I can also get the user info by using `guard('agent')->user()`.
However, it does not log the user into the application. It loop back to the login page. Any help would be appreciated.

Guard Code:

```
'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
        'hash' => false,
    ],
    'agent' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'agents',
    ],
],
```

Provider Code:

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    'agents' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Agent::class,
    ],
],
```

Comment: Have you got the code for the custom guard available?

Answer (score 0):

instead of using  `$this->guard()->attempt(`

replaced it to

```
auth()->attempt([$this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')])
```

if you want to use the default guard or if you want to use specific guard just do it this way. we'll use your existing guards that can be used.

```
auth('agent')->attempt([$this->credentials($request), $request->filled('remember')])
```

Comment: $this->guard()->attempt is part of the AuthenticatesUsers file. I have added the guard 'agent' so it would fetch from the agent model. Auth::guard('agent')->attempt($request->only('email','password'),$request->filled('remember')) also return success. The problem is it loop back to log in page rather than sign in.